# How to overwrite a value in a Select statement with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables and both of these tables have many columns. However they have one column which has the same name for purpose.

Now, I want to select from both of these tables, but I want my second table's value to overwrite the first table's value.

Something like this:

```
SELECT d.*,
IFNULL((SELECT animal FROM test2 WHERE id = 1), d.animal) as animal
FROM test1 as d
WHERE d.id = 5
```

So basically what I want is if it finds an animal in the second table, overwrite the first one to the exact same name, else does not do anything.

It is important that the query must need to a result for the name of "animal", because the whole application is depending on it.

Is it possible in an easy way?

Comment: Why is id = 1 in test2 and id = 5 in test1? Basically, you want to join your tables and use a case statement... but you need to have some sort of join key between the two tables, unless you plan on manually providing both of your tables' ids every time

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Your query looks reasonable.  What is the problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I get the following error: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'animal'

Comment: @evanv The two table is separate. I've entered those values to demonstrate that they are not the same ids.

Comment: How are these tables related then? Do you plan on entering those two ids manually? And how would you do that? Eyeball the tables and find the values you want?

Comment: @evanv No. These are just examples, I'm getting them from the database and using a placeholder in the real code. The question however is, how to overwrite thoe values if the second query gets a match. :)

Comment: "The question however is, how to overwrite thoe values if the second query gets a match"  -- if that is so, then what I am saying is your question does not make sense. A match on what? How are these tables related?

Comment: @evanv If you take a look at the query, you will instantly find out how they are related. I have also explained in the first post, that they have one same column name which is the 'animals'. I wrote "if the second query gets a match" becuase if you take a look at the 2nd query, it must have a result = it has a match.

Comment: I did look at the query. And I assure you that what you have posted here does not define nor imply a relationship of any kind. Prove it to yourself. Say you have two tables. The both have an "id" column and an "address" column. They also have 100 rows each. The ids don't match. Neither do the addresses. And I want to grab the address from the second table when there is a match.... but a match on what? The fact that there is a column called address? Which of the 100 addresses in the second table would I use, and where? Your question does not make sense, as stated.

Comment: @evanv Thanks for the detailed answer. If you look at the quesry once again, you will find out, that there should not be any connection (eg.: foreign key) between the two tables. I've never stated that there is a connection like that. I have only mentioned, that they have a column which have the same name. What I want is, that based on 2 totally different search criteria, if one has a result do that, if it gives back null, then go with the original value. It does makes sense, you just need to look atit more carefully.

Comment: I would recommend reading about the relational model and SQL in general. The columns don't need to match. In fact it means literally nothing if they do. Whether it's for a class or a client or an employer, your question and discussion here make it very clear that you don't understand SQL and the relational model correctly. You should probably look into those a bit more, and best of luck.

Comment: @evanv It looks like you do not really get my question's logic. Trust me I have read a lot about the relational model, but I do not want them to relate. This is what you don't get.

Comment: And it seems that you went on a negative voting spree of a hissy feet. Again, best of luck of luck to you. Hopefully someone in the community at large can follow the logic of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem would presumably be that `d.*` has a column named `animal` in it.  Just give the new column a different alias:

```
SELECT d.*,
       IFNULL((SELECT t2.animal FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.id = 1), d.animal) as new_animal
FROM test1 d
WHERE d.id = 5;
```

Or list out all the columns individually, but not including the old `animal`:

```
SELECT d.col1, d.col2, . . .,
       IFNULL((SELECT t2.animal FROM test2 t2 WHERE t2.id = 1), d.animal) as new_animal
FROM test1 d
WHERE d.id = 5;
```